# SHKTwitter's followMe function in iphone

Tags: ios4

I don't know how to implement the twitter followMe feature.

I found the SHKTwitter's followMe function, but I haven't any reference informations about it.

Please tell me or send a bit of samples.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code, you'll see that it's basically making a Twitter API request to  add the account defined in "SHKTwitterUsername" (SHKConfig.h) to the user's friends list (follows).

So, if you have a Twitter account for tweeting to your app users, you can add a follow button in your app that calls [SHKTwitter followme], and configure SHKTwitterUsername to your twitter handle.

Hope this helps!